# Difference between evaluating and performing IO actions: what causes Haskell to perform IO?

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation

What mechanism does Haskell use to actually decide to invoke the 4 actions below?

```
main :: IO ()
main = getLine >>= putStrLn >> getLine >>= putStrLn
```

Initially I thought it was to do with lazy evaluation, but... as from Real Word Haskell, about IO actions, they

> produce an effect when performed, but not when evaluated

So I suspect it's some other mechanism rather than the system wanting to "evaluate" `main`. What is this mechanism? Or if it is evaluation, what is Haskell "wanting" to evaluate that causes it to execute the chain of actions?

Comment: Related, but probably not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647852/haskell-actual-io-monad-implementation-in-different-language

Comment: Also related: [*Newbie: understanding main and IO()*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12226624/2751851)

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829618/functional-programming-where-does-the-side-effect-actually-happen .

Answer (score 12):

As a first order approximation, the *only* source of evaluation in a Haskell program is `main`. What that means is that:

- `IO` actions can be assembled and composed through `>>=`, `>>`, `<*>`, `fmap`, etc to produce any other `IO` actions but
- only the `main` `IO` action will ever produce effects.

In a sense all a Haskell program ever does is run `main :: IO ()`. For anything to be evaluated, it has to stand in the way of running the `IO` action (this is where laziness fits). That begs the question: *what does it mean to actually run an `IO` action*?

Under the hood, `IO` ends up behaving like a (strict) `State` monad that threads through it a [`RealWorld`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#t:RealWorld) state (which contains no information - it is symbolic of the state that side-effects encompass on the world), so "running" `IO` (sort of equivalent to `State RealWorld`) is like calling [`runState`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:runState). Naturally, this `runState` can occur only once for any program - and this is exactly what `main` does (and what makes it magical)!

Answer (score 9):

It may seem strange, but running IO actions is actually outside the scope of ordinary Haskell language!<sup>1</sup>

The Haskell built in libraries provide "basic" IO actions like `getLine :: IO String`, functions that return IO actions like `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`, and ways of building IO actions out of other IO actions (mostly by providing a `Monad` interface, so anything that works on any monad like all the stuff in `Control.Monad` is a way of working with `IO`).

All of that is pure and lazy, in exactly the same way that non-IO Haskell code is. `IO` is *not* a special case for anything you can do with ordinary Haskell code (which is why you can use Monad-generic code on IO; all that code is written and compiled without any knowledge of any special rules that IO has, so it could only work if there aren't any).

But none of that actually ever performs an IO action; it just makes new IO actions out of other ones. This is what people mean when they talk about how "evaluating an IO action doesn't produce an effect". A value `"apple" ++ "banana"` of type `String` can be represented by an unevaluated thunk; when it gets evaluated to `"applebanana"` it still represents exactly the same value, the system just has it recorded as data in memory rather than a pointer to some code that could be run to produce it<sup>1</sup>. In exactly the same way a value `putStrLn "apple" >> putStrLn "banana"` of type `IO ()` can be represented by an unevaluated thunk, and when it gets evaluated all that means is that the system is now representing *that same value* with a data structure instead of a pointer to code that will run the (pure, lazy) function `>>` on two other IO actions. But we've only talked about the system's in-memory representation of the IO action, nothing about actually running them to produce some side effects.

And there actually **are** no language features of Haskell that talk about how IO actions are performed. The runtime system "just knows" how to execute the `main` IO action from the `Main` module<sup>3</sup>. The Haskell language has no way of talking about how or whether that happens; that's all handled by the system that provides Haskell to you (GHC, or another Haskell system). The only option the Haskell language gives you is that `main` is defined as a Haskell action; any IO actions that you incorporate as part of the definition of `main` will get run.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm pretending that things like `unsafePerformIO` do not exist for the purpose of this discussion. As the name implies, it *deliberately* breaks the normal rules. It's also not intended for introducing "performing IO actions" as a normal part of the Haskell language, but only for use in the internals of something that presents a "normal Haskell" interface.

<sup>2</sup> Usually this happens partially: only very basic types like `Int` are "all-or-nothing" evaluated. Most can be partially evaluated to data structures that contain thunks deeper down (which may or may not themselves get evaluated later).

<sup>3</sup> Or GHCi "just knows" how to execute IO actions that you enter at its prompt.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://wiki.haskell.org/IO_inside#Welcome_to_the_RealWorld.2C_baby, there is a "fake" type that represents the real world, `RealWorld`, and `IO (a)` is actually a function.

```
type IO a  =  RealWorld -> (a, RealWorld)
```

So `main`, as you might expect in other languages, is actually a function

```
main :: RealWorld -> ((), RealWorld)
```

that is called when the program runs. So to evaluate the final output, which is of type `((), RealWorld)`, Haskell needs to get the value of the `RealWorld` component, and in order to do that, it must run the `main` function. Note: it's the runtime that cause this function to run. There is no way in Haskell to trigger the execution of this function.

In the case of

```
main = getLine >>= putStrLn >> getLine >>= putStrLn
```

each of the actions are actually functions, and to work out the `RealWorld` value output at the end of the final `putStrLn`, it would need to run it, and all the actions leading up to it.

So it *is* lazy evaluation, but of the *hidden* `RealWorld` value.

Comment: `RealWorld` is fake.  I didn't know Haskell was so philosophical